# Case insentitive string comparison in PHP

Tags: php, string, if-statement, case-insensitive

When I'm doing an `if` statement, it doesn't work if the string is a uppercase word because it grabs the word of my search string.

Example:

> index.php?channel=test

```
<?php
    $channel_query = $_GET['channel'];
    $channel_query = $_GET['channel'];
    if ($channel_query == "test") {
        echo "Claimed";
    } elseif($channel_query == "test1") {
        echo "Claimed";
    }
    if(strtolower($channel_query) == strtolower($channel_query)){
    } else
        echo "N/A";
```

So if the string is "Test", it doesn't work because it's uppercase. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

You could normalize the case of both strings.

Example using [`strtolower()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php):

```
if (strtolower($channel_query) == 'test') {
  // code...
}
```

Comment: Or for more than just ASCII english: `mb_strtolower($utf8)`

Comment: @Xeoncross, indeed. There are others ways too, such as `strcasecmp()`. I offered `strtolower()` as the OP had instances in their code.